# Define a color function using Piecewise

Tags: plotting, functions, color

How can I define a `ColorFunction` for my `ContourPlot` using `Piecewise`? For example, after making a `ContourPlot` for this function:

```
p[x_, y_] := 1 - Sin[x]^2 Sin[y]^2;
```

I want to define my `ColorFunction` in a way that for example for `0 < p < 0.1` the plot have a different color than `0.1 < p < 0.2`. An example of what I need is in the following plot:
[image: my example]

where the colorbar at the right shows that each color corresponds to a value of `p`.

Comment: Doesn't it just work by default? `ContourPlot[1 - Sin[x]^2*Sin[y]^2, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]`

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Kaurov The thing is that I need to have control on the colors. In the plot that I have put as an example, e.g. dark orange corresponds to `0.8<p<0.9`. `ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"` doesn't give me this option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
myBlend[x_] := Blend[{Purple, Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Orange, Red}, x]
ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 Contours -> 25, ColorFunction -> myBlend]
```

or

```
myPiecewise[x_] := Piecewise[{{Red, 0 <= x <= 0.25}, 
  {Orange, 0.25 < x <= 0.75}, {Yellow, 0.75 < x <= 1}]
ContourPlot[p[x, y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunction -> myPiecewise, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Remember to put `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` if you need precise control over the position of the colours.

```
<< PlotLegends`
ShowLegend[
  ContourPlot[2 p[x, y], {x, 0, \[Pi]}, {y, 0, \[Pi]}, 
     ColorFunction -> myPiecewise],
  {myPiecewise, 10, "0", "1", LegendPosition -> {1.1, 0}}]
```

[guide/PlotLegendsPackage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage.html)

Note: I work with version 8. In version 9 it appears to have been integrated: [ref/BarLegend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BarLegend.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Do you know how can I build that color column at the right hand side of the plot in the question? I need to explain the colors using that.

Answer (score 4):

There's another syntax for `Blend` which lets you control the color-banding easily:

```
cf = Blend[{
    {0., Blue}, 
    {0.1, Green},
    {0.15, Black},
    {0.2, Red}, 
    {0.8, Purple},
    {0.95, Cyan}
    }, #1] & 

 DensityPlot[Sin[a] Sin[b],
   {a, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   {b, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotPoints -> 250,
   ColorFunction -> cf ,
   MaxRecursion -> 2,
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: color function and densityplot]