# ListPlot - coloring negative and positive points

Tags: plotting

how to create a point graph(ListPlot?), where the positive values will be BLUE, negative RED and 0 values will be green?

Thanks.

Comment: The best answer was chosen after 43 minutes, 8 minutes after the first submission was made, after only 19 views and zero votes, while Asians and Pacific Islanders sleep,.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE, please take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up both questions and answers. Don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its likely that the best approaches may come later improving over a previous reply. Wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first solution is a basic one, but it does the trick.
For a second solution involving `ColorFunction`, see below.

I assume that you have a list of points, such as

```
ptList = {{1, -2}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, -4}, {7, -6.5}, {8,  2}, {9, 0}, {10, 5}};
```

and that you are interested in whether the second coordinate is postive, negative or zero.
First you can extract the negative and positive elements from the list:

```
listNeg = Cases[ptList, x_ /; Negative[x[[2]]]]
(* {{1, -2}, {6, -4}, {7, -6.5}} *)
listPos = Cases[ptList, x_ /; Positive[x[[2]]]]
(* {{2, 5}, {3, 6}, {5, 1}, {8, 2}, {10, 5}} *)
```

The rest is automatically zero:

```
listZero = Complement[ptList, Join[listNeg, listPos]]
(* {{4, 0}, {9, 0}} *)
```

Then you can plot the three different lists, each with their own color:

```
ListPlot[{listPos, listNeg, listZero}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

which gives the result:

[image: Color graph]

Alternatively, you can put everything into one `ListPlot` command, which may  save some memory when you are dealing with large lists. In that case, you can no longer use `Complement` to find the zero elements, but you should check for them instead:

```
ListPlot[{Cases[ptList, x_ /; Positive[x[[2]]]], Cases[ptList, x_ /; Negative[x[[2]]]], Cases[ptList, x_ /; x[[2]] == 0]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

This gives you the same result as before.

**Edit: a second solution using ColorFunction**

Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688088/individual-point-coloring-in-listplot-errorlistplot-in-mathematica) that funnypony referred to and based on an answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/define-a-color-function-using-piecewise) question, here is a second solution.

First you define your own `ColorFunction` using `Piecewise`

```
myColorFunc[x_] := Piecewise[{{Blue, x > 0}, {Green, x == 0}, {Red, x < 0}}]
```

Then, you use `ListLinePlot` with a replacement rule

```
ListLinePlot[ptList, ColorFunction -> myColorFunc, ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. Line[arg___] :> Point[arg]
```

which gives the same result as before, albeit with square plot markers instead of round ones.

Answer (score 5):

You can `Style` individual data points without having to partition the dataset:

```
data = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, 30];
cf = Function[{y}, Piecewise[{{Red, y < 0}, {Blue, y > 0}}, Green]];
styleddata = Style[#, cf@#, PointSize[Large]] & /@ data;
ListPlot[styleddata, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

If the data is a list of pairs, apply the coloring function `cf` to the second elements of the pairs:

```
data2 = {#, RandomInteger[{-3, 3}]} & /@ Range[30];
styleddata2 = Style[#, cf@#[[2]], PointSize[Large]] & /@ data2;
ListPlot[styleddata2, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{data2, styleddata2}, Joined -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 300,
 Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, {LightRed, LightBlue}}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not brilliant, but working:

```
data = Table[{i, RandomInteger[{-2, 2}]}, {i, 200}];
crit = {#[[2]] < 0 &, #[[2]] == 0 &, #[[2]] > 0 &};
ListPlot[Through[(Select /@ crit)[data]], PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Other ideas utilizing ColorFunction can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688088/individual-point-coloring-in-listplot-errorlistplot-in-mathematica)