# How can I combine two color schemes for plotting?

Tags: plotting, color

I want to use ListContourPlot to display all negative values using one colorscheme and all positive values using another color scheme. This question [Define a color function using Piecewise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/define-a-color-function-using-piecewise) gives some hints, but if I use something like this

```
colorFunc[x_] := Piecewise[{{"AlpineColors", x >= 0},
{"SouthwestColors", x < 0}}];

ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> colorFunc]
```

I get the error message:

> AlpineColors is not a Graphics primitive or directive

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Edit1:
I used kguler's suggestion which works with most data. However, in some cases I get results like this:
[image]

using

```
ListContourPlot[data, Contours -> 10,ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData["NeonColors"][#], # > 0.5}, {ColorData["Aquamarine"][#], # <= 0.5}}] &),ContourLabels -> All]
```

The Aquamarine colors should code only for negative values and not for positive ones. What does go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Note that according to the docs, "`ColorFunction -> "name"` is equivalent to `ColorFunction -> (ColorData["name"][#i]&)` where the slot used is as follows...."  Using a string name is a special case and the string has to appear by itself after the `->` for it to be handled as a `ColorData` name for you.  To do what you want, you have to do all the work in your program, as in the answer(s).

Comment: Regarding your edit try adding `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
 ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData["AlpineColors"][#], # >= .5}, 
                              {ColorData["SouthwestColors"][#], # < .5}}] &)]
```

[image]

**Update:** Rescaling the range of the function `ColorData[_scheme_]`using the form  `ColorData[{_scheme_, {min, max}}]` together with the option `ColorFunctionScaling->False` gives more control:

```
dt = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
{min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@dt;
ListContourPlot[dt, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData[{"AlpineColors", {min, max}}][#], # >= 0},
            {ColorData[{"SouthwestColors", {min, max}}][#], # < 0}}] &)]
(* same picture *)
```

**Update 2:** Dealing with the issue mention in the comments:

In version 9

```
dt = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}]; dt[[10, 10]] = -0.01;
{min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@dt;
ListContourPlot[dt, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ContourLabels -> True, MaxPlotPoints -> 500,
 ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{ColorData[{"AlpineColors", {min, max}}][#], # >= 0},
      {ColorData[{"SouthwestColors", {min, max}}][#], # < 0}}] &)]
```

gives

[image]

Using the option `InterpolationOrder->0` I get:
[image]

Zooming in around `dt[[10,10]]` using `PlotRange -> {{9.75, 10.25}, {9.75, 10.25}}`, I get

[image]

Comment: It is uncanny how often I start reading an chart/plot answer and say to myself "I bet this is written by @kgular" and then scroll down and sure enough!!

Comment: Rescaling helps, but there are still undesired results, e.g. when using: dt = Table[Abs[Sin[i + j^2]], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}]; 
dt[[10, 10]] = -0.01;

Comment: @user120162, I think due to sampling the isolated point  `dt[[10,100]]` is not visible. You can see that it is colored correctly if you use the option `InterpolationOrder->0` or zoom in around that point using, say, `PlotRange -> {{9.5, 10.5}, {9.5, 10.5}}`.

Comment: @kguler: The isolation point is just an illustration for the problems that can be caused. The colouring, however, is wrong also in other areas. Positive values very close to zero are also depicted as negative, see here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=149qq8m&s=8#.VLd5hl0UNZx

Comment: @user120162, this may also be version issue. I will post what i get using v9 (windows 8 64 bit).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, it can't be _my style_; i think it is just that the probability `answerer== kguler`  conditional on `tag==chat|plot` must be high:)

Comment: @kguler, using InterpolationOrder->0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False and zooming in as you suggested revealed some 'singular' points in my data that were causing the problems.

Comment: @user120162, glad the problem is solved. Thank you for the accept